Deploying Python-based Chat Bots for MS Teams
I am trying to deploy a simple Microsoft Teams using one of the provided samples, but I cannot seem to get it running.
Here are the steps that I followed:

Cloned the the BotBuilder-Samples repository and navigated to the
Python Echo Bot sample.
Ran the app using python app.py after creating a virtual
environment and installing the dependencies.
Started a ngrok tunnel for the running application using ngrok http 3879.
Attempted to register the bot at https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new. I chose a Single Tenant app, created an App Registration in my Azure tenant and pasted the App ID and the App Tenant ID in the given fields. The Messaging Endpoint that I registered was https://2aa2-2302-d987-9090-188v-e73d-45c1-24ae-3a25.ngrok-free.app/api/messages.
Added Microsoft Teams as a channel; this redirected me to Microsoft Teams, to a chat with the bot, however, I cannot send any messages to the bot (screenshot given below). I am unable to send any messages to the bot via the web UI either because I am faced with the following error:


There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
Unauthorized


What am I doing wrong here?
I also have a couple of other related questions,

When I am deploying this bot in production is it necessary for me to
use the Azure Bot Service? Or as long as I register it in the above
portal (with the correct messaging endpoint), can I deploy it
anywhere I like?
Although it is not working for me at the moment, I can see how one
is to interact with the bot via direct messages, but is it also
possible to add it to a channel and receive messages when the bot is
mentioned?

I've already had a look at this, but I believe my question is more specific.
Note: I am quite open to other approaches to deploying the bot, however, I do not want to be tied to an Azure service and I want to be able to deploy the bot in my own server.

So you can definitely deploy it elsewhere, you just need the bot "Registration" in Azure Bot Framework Services. Separately, your bot needs to be a "multi-tenant" app though, so it can connect between Teams, Bot Framework Services, and your backend.

I have created a new registration by choosing the mult-tenant app type and using a multi-tenant app registration, but it did not make any difference.

Where are you seeing the Unauthorized error?

In the ngrok console and in the web UI as well; in the channels section, under issues.

Was just logging in to reply about the AppId/App Password but I see you've found it - nice.

Thank you for your help, Hilton. Do you know if there is any way to get the bots to reply on channels?

I'm not totally following your question, but maybe this will help - you -can- add a bot to a channel, and it can indeed reply. It -won't- receive the messages in a channel though unless it's @mentioned - very important to know

Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to know. How can I do this exactly?

Is your bot deployed as an app in Teams? If so, just go to the Apps list in the Team and add it, then it will be available in the channel

Hilton, could you please explain to me how to deploy the bot as an app. I do not know how to do this. Maybe you can add this as an answer? As an extension to what I have provided above?

For that you should definitely start with the documentation - check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/what-are-bots as a starting point

Hilton, I apologize if I am missing something, but I read through this document and I cannot find anything on how to deploy the bot as an app. Do you have something more specific?

Sure, have a look at this sample, linked off the docs: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-conversation/python . The "appManifest" folder in particular is what you want. You need the three files inside there zipped into a zip file, which is your "app package" that you upload to Teams. If you're just doing this in one tenant, you use the Teams Admin centre. If you want to submit to the store, that's a bigger process but you need to test locally first anyway

Thanks, Hilton. There is one other approach that worked for me. I created an app via the Developer Portal -> Selected the Bot feature under App features -> Selected the bot that I registered at https://dev.botframework.com. Is this an acceptable way to go about this?

So, I've made two mistakes:

I need to add a few environment variables to get the Echo Bot running. These are accessed in config.py. The environment variables that need to be set are MicrosoftAppId, MicrosoftAppPassword, MicrosoftAppType and MicrosoftAppTenantId.
The 'Upload custom apps' setting needs to be enabled organization-wide via the Microsoft Teams Admin Center.


With this, I was able to get my bot running.
However, I am still not sure if there is a possibility of adding the bot to specific channels though.
